# Can TaggedTempalte have overload signatures with a certain string literal argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```js
declare function taggedFn(x: ['strange']): 123;
declare function taggedFn(x: TemplateStringsArray): string;

// OK
var v1: string = taggedFn`ordinary`;

// NG: How can I hit the ['strange'] signature?
var v2: 123 = taggedFn`strange`;
```

- I have a TaggedTemplate function
- I can control its signatures
- I want it to return `string` on a normal call
- I want it to return `123` when a argument is `strange` (**NG**)

Basically it's possible for a normal function by overloading but how can we with TaggedTemplate function? Is it possible to overload it with a certain argument?

[Here's a working example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=33#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwygHMiRgAxVACgA8AueAbQHIBnDGKVU5gXQEoGARgBMAZgDcAWABQoSLAQp02PAWKkK1evAAqIALYAHaBhABlDlm6sAgjE4BPQfHYxrRaTNkB6H-AB5AGlZADdYeFChBjcPeABedRIySgADHBhga1hHVK9ffwA5AHEGAAkcAHd4MC54AEl4AAssDAImhBY3Lh5eVywiVCgMZDgAfjCI0JFhcQSkzTTu7hA8oA)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33304) in TS issue tracker to add support for this.